# NGRX effect doesn't return success action

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I want to fetch posts via `ngrx/effects`, I dispatch it on `ngOnInit`, on devtools it shows that is dispatched but there is no success action. 
Here is the effect code:

```
   @Effect()
    loadPosts$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
        .ofType(PostActions.LOAD_POSTS)
        .switchMap(() => {
            return this.postService.getPosts()
                .map(posts => ({ type: PostActions.LOAD_POSTS_SUCCESS, payload: posts }));
        });
```

And also what is the best way to display these posts?

Comment: Are you sure that the effect is acutally handled? I see nothing obvious wrong, so maybe you forgot to register your effect class? Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the function passed to the switchMap?

Comment: As for your second point, you should probably ask a new question. But usually you have a reducer that updates the application state, then you use the store and a selector in your component to query this part of the state.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did, but it works now, maybe the order in app.module was wrong. Now I got this message on Redux Devtools: `TypeError: action.payload.slice is not a function`